# how to extracting data from pymodbus?

Tags: python, modbus

I have a simple program to retrive data from modbus, and I want to extract it..

```
from pyModbusTCP.client import ModbusClient

c = ModbusClient(host="192.168.1.64", port=502, auto_open=True)
regs = c.read_holding_registers(0, 4)
print (regs)
```

output:

```
[ 1 , 23 , 21 , 42 ]
```

how to extract output to variable like

```
a = 1
b = 23
c = 21
d = 42
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access a list item with numeric list indices, starting at 0:

```
l = [ 1 , 23 , 21 , 42 ]

a = l[0]
b = l[1]
c = l[2]
d = l[3]
```

But if you do not know something that basic, you should read a book on Python first.